# Find $\tan(x+y)$ given $\sin x=3\sin(x+2y)$

Tags: trigonometry

> If $\sin x=3\sin(x+2y)$, then find $\tan(x+y)$

My reference gives the solution $-2\tan y$, but how do I prove it ?

**My Attempt**
$$
3=\frac{\sin(x+2y)}{\sin x}\implies3\sin x=\sin x.\cos2y+\cos x.\sin2y\\
3\sin x=2\sin x.\cos^2y-\sin x+2\cos x.\sin y.\cos y=2\cos y.\sin(x+y)-\sin x\\
\implies 4\sin x=2\cos y.\sin(x+y)\implies\sin(x+y)=2.\frac{\sin x}{\cos y}\\
\cos(x+y)=\frac{\sin x}{\sin y}\implies\boxed{\tan(x+y)=2\tan y}
$$

It seems like the solution is +ve, how can it be a negative solution as given in my reference ?

Comment: The very first step $3=\frac{\sin(x+2y)}{\sin x}$ is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$
\frac{\sin(x+2y)}{\sin x}=\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{\sin(x+2y)+\sin x}{\sin(x+2y)-\sin x}=\frac{1+3}{1-3}=-2\\
\frac{2\sin(x+y)\cos y}{2\cos(x+y)\sin y}=-2\implies\frac{\tan(x+y)}{\tan y}=-2\\
\implies\tan(x+y)=-2\tan y
$$

Comment: I don't understand the first step.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

As we need to eliminate $x$

let $x+y=k,x=k-y$

$$\sin(y-k)=3\sin(k-y+2y)$$

**Method**$\#1:$

Expand $\sin(y-k),\sin(y+k)$   and group $\sin k,\cos k$

**Method**$\#2:$

$$\dfrac{\sin(y-k)}{\sin(y+k)}=\dfrac31$$

Apply [Componendo dividendo](https://suresolv.com/basic-maths/componendo-dividendo-algebra)

Answer (score 1):

Rewrite the given equality as $$\sin\left(\left(x+y\right)-y\right) = 3\sin\left(\left(x+y\right)+y\right).$$ Now use the formula for $\sin\left(A+B\right)$ on both sides and simplify.

Answer (score 1):

Let indicate $x+y=z$, then

$$\sin x =3\sin(x+2y) \iff \sin (z-y)=3\sin (z+y)$$

$$\sin z\cos y-\cos z\sin y=3\sin z \cos y + 3 \cos z \sin y$$

$$-2\sin z\cos y= 4 \cos z \sin y \implies \tan z=\tan (x+y)=-2\tan y$$